# SQL Query Primary Key constraint

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie in sql. Can someone please enlighten me on the following sql query. My problem lies in `staffID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(personID)`

```
$sql   =   "CREATE   TABLE   Persons(staffID   int   NOT   NULL 
AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY  KEY(personID),FirstName  varchar(15),LastName  varchar(15),Age 
int)";
```

Thank you. 
Regards.

Comment: What's personid? Obviously, staffid is the pk. And storing age is a silly idea

Comment: Your AUTO_INCREMENT column should be your PK. Also, you need to define personID as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a primary key of an invalid column, as well as omitting an auto increment column. Please try with the below SQL.  See this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) from MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE Persons(staffId INT AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     personId VARCHAR(10),
     firstName VARCHAR(15), 
     LastName VARCHAR(15),
     Age INT, 
     primary key (staffId,personId));
```

Comment: Please explain this statement 

`staffID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(personID)`

Comment: As per SQL definitions, primary key has to be an available column in a table which is by default NOT NULL and UNIQUE. Your SQL statement in the SO does not even have the column. So first create the column and use it as primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Auto_increment column should be int type & primary key. but your sql statement is wrong where staff_id is not primary key. You can set staffid to primary key and person to unique key

```
$sql   =   "CREATE   TABLE   Persons(staffId int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT
, personid int unique key not null , FirstName  varchar(15),LastName  varchar(15), Age int)";
```

Comment: Please explain this statement 

`staffID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(personID)`

Comment: @yetin Auto_increment column should be int and Primary key. staffID is define auto_increment but it is not declared as primary key. Thas why it is error.